# By picking a different parameterization the normal vector is not always defined. Why?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I stumbled upon a problem on surface integrals which required a parameterization of the cylinder (upper half-cylinder). My surface is $z = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. I found it odd that the normal vector $\vec n = \left< \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}, 0 , 1 \right>$ of the parameterization  $r(x,y)=\left< x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2}\right>$ is not defined at the border of the upper half-cylinder $\ e.g.\ P_0=\left(1,0,0\right)$. I would guess that this would just be a vector with the direction of the position vector $\vec{OP_0}$

1. Why is it not and why does a more classic parameterization $\ e.g. \
       r(θ,z)=\left< cosθ, sinθ, z\right>, \ \vec n_o = \left< sinθ, cosθ ,
       0 \right>$ not have this problem at that point?
2. What does this *generally* mean for picking a parameterization

Comment: You can observe that the vector $\vec{n} = (x^2/(1-x^2), 0, 1)$ in the limit as $x \to 0$ becomes more and more parallel with the vector $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: So by choosing the second parameterization you avoid this improper integral?